# How to compare java.sql.Timestamp and java.util.Date

Tags: java, mysql, date, java-6, sql-timestamp

I know java Date was poor designed, but I don't know how until today.

I saved a date to DB and when I get it from DB and compare to original date, it told me it's different!

And I wrote a test which looks strange but it PASSED!

```
@Test
public void date_equals() {
    Date now = new Date();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());

    assertFalse(timestamp.equals(now));
    assertTrue(now.equals(timestamp));

    assertTrue(timestamp.compareTo(now) == 0);
    assertFalse(now.compareTo(timestamp) == 0);

    assertTrue(timestamp.getTime() == now.getTime());
    assertTrue(now.getTime() == timestamp.getTime());
}
```

I noticed that java.sql.Timestamp has a little different than Date about nanoseconds which I don't care.

Can anyone told me how to compare this two in best practice?
I don't want to compare date use getTime() everywhere, is there any common library or other ways to do this?

BTW I'm using JDK 6

Comment: The Javadoc for Timestamp says that the equals method is not symmetric.  I guess if you need to use equals, make sure you specify the Date before the Timestamp.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: @BasilBourque Has to be java.util.Date, because he's using a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
originalInstant.equals( 
    org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant( mySqlTimestamp ) 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are an awful mess, with poor designs and awkward hacks. One of those bad hacks is making `java.sql.Timestamp` a subclass of `java.util.Date` while telling you to ignore that fact of inheritance.

To quote [the class doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) (emphasis mine):

> Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is **recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date**. The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

You were told to pretend they are *not* related classes. So your attempt to compare objects of each type is inappropriate.

### Data loss

The `Timestamp` has a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). The `java.util.Date` class is limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). So the two will not compare as equal.

## Using java.time

Instead, use the java.time classes. Much of their functionality is available as a back-port to Java 6 – see below.

When you get your `Timestamp`, immediately convert to the java.time types. In Java 8 and later you could call the new methods added to those old classes for conversion. In the ThreeTen-Backport library for Java 6 & 7, use [`org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant( Timestamp )`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html#toInstant-java.sql.Timestamp-)

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant( mySqlTimestamp ) ;
```

Now compare to your original `Instant`.

```
boolean isOriginal = originalInstant.equals( instant ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Damn, after your latest edit, I want to upvote this a second time.

Answer (score 1):

You have [`Timestamp::compareTo(java.util.Date o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) in [`java.sql.TimeStamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class. Use it.

Comment: OP said he already tried that, and it didn't give the desired result.

Comment: This worked for me -- `timestamp.equals(date)` returned `false` while `timestamp.compareTo(date)` returned `0`.